# CPU temperature increase after additional video card installation

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, intel-core2

I have a `quad-core Intel Core 2 Duo Q6600 CPU`

Today I added a second video card and my CPU temperature increased to `88ºC`. I want to know whether my video card or something else caused this. I've checked my fan speed with SpeedFan, and it showed a normal reading of 2500 RPM.

Just an FYI, I live in a region with a hot climate.

Comment: You probably need to look at the bigger picture - Your case and its cooling capabilities, and the processor load with one and two cards.

Comment: You need to remember what was your temperature before adding the card. Maybe you were running on 88C all the time unknowingly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really sketchy and provides little detail, but from what I gather, your problem is from one of two reasons (or both):

1) Your CPU runs at 88ºC all the time and you only noticed it now. Being in a hot climate, this isn't very strange. If you really want a lower temperature, install a faster fan.

2) You haven't configured the video card correctly, and as a result of this, your computer isn't communicating with it efficiently, and is dumping data onto your CPU instead. Re-read the instructions on your new card and see whether you went wrong.

3) The extra heat from the card isn't being blown out effectively, and is causing the overall temperature of the system to go up.

Comment: Third possibility - the extra heat from the card isn't being blown out effectively, and is causing the overall temperature of the system to go up.

Comment: Edited to add that possibility.